# What is an HTTP subscription?

Tags: exchange-2007, http, exchange-2010, exchange, subscription

Specifically I'm trying to get a better understanding of Exchange Web Services (EWS) and I see many references to EWS subscriptions.  It appears that a 'subscription' is a generic HTTP concept but I haven't had much success searching 'subscriptions' online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the context (link to a document you're seeing this term?), I have two educated guesses:

You may be referring to [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) subscriptions, which are (in one use) a way of maintaining a easily-parsed listing of updates on a website. I believe that you can also turn a mailbox into an RSS feed with EWS.

You may also be referring to push or [pull subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579617%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) within the EWS API, meant to allow developers to query for change events within the mailbox store. Unless you're coding an application that will interface with EWS, this is likely not what you're looking for.

Comment: I apologize, I don't even know enough to give an educated question.  Let me dig up the exact context again and I'll come back.  I was hoping it was simply an HTTP connection term.

Comment: No problem. It's most likely one of those two.

Comment: It is in fact referring to your second guess; Specifically a Cisco Unity server was experiencing an MWI delay.  I have seen the term elsewhere but cannot recall where.  I hated to ask such a vague question but there isn't much info on this generic term.